# How can i override an attribute from another virtual attribute in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, virtual-attribute

I have a virtual attribute `start_date` and a database column `start` (datetime).

How can i override the date (but not the time) of `start` with the date from `start_date`?

I tried this in the setter method and the logger says that self.start/start is set, but in the database and also the update log `start` has still the old date.

```
# model: db table with columns: id(int), start(datetime)
class DateTimeTest < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :start_date, :start

  def start_date=(value)
    logger.debug '>>>>' + start.inspect
    logger.debug '>>>>' + self.start.inspect
    start = DateTime.new(value.to_date.year, value.to_date.month, value.to_date.mday, 15,15,15)
    self.start = DateTime.new(value.to_date.year, value.to_date.month, value.to_date.mday, 15,15,15)
    logger.debug '>>>>' + start.inspect
    logger.debug '>>>>' + self.start.inspect
  end

end

# view
<%= simple_form_for(@datetimetest) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :start_date, :as => :string %>
  <%= f.input :start %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

# controller is a base scaffolding controller
```

In the logs i can see that `start` is populated:

```
Parameters: {..., "datetimetest"=>{"start_date"=>"03.05.2012", "start(1i)"=>"2012", "start(2i)"=>"5", "start(3i)"=>"1", "start(4i)"=>"13", "start(5i)"=>"05"}
```

Comment: Are you *absolutely* certain that in your class instance the self.start attribute has been initialized with a value?

Comment: I have the following in the log: Parameters: {..., "datetimetest"=>{"start_date"=>"03.05.2012", "start(1i)"=>"2012", "start(2i)"=>"5", "start(3i)"=>"1", "start(4i)"=>"13", "start(5i)"=>"05"} Also if add a setter method for start and do a logger.debug value.inspect i got the datetime.

Comment: Start is a database column so this should be set through basic accessors.

Comment: Is it possible to post more of the class in question?

Comment: What rails version are you using? I've set up an app more or less the same as what you describe, and I have no problems.

Comment: I am using 3.2.3. Started over again with a fresh setup and now i got the right logger output. I can also set the new start date and debug this start_date in log. But this does not override my start value. I pasted the whole code here: http://pastebin.com/wTdqPYUE

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. I tried the self.start = DateTime.new(...) version of what you have in pastebin, and it worked fine.

Comment: Strange, still not working here...In the log i got the right result, in the sql update its still the old date.

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime decomposes into year, month, date of month, hour, minute, and second, but does not conveniently break into date and time.

```
def start_date(value)
  start = DateTime.new(value.year, value.month, value.mday,
                       start.hour, start.minute, start.second)
  logger.debug self.start.inspect
end
```

Comment: My problem is that i can not access start. I tried your method and also self.start but both are nil.

Comment: Then your problem is that you have not set start yet.  Either set start, or add code for if start.nil?.

Comment: Mh, start is a database column so this should be set through basic accessors.